# Transferring variable from server socket to specific client socket

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm attempting to transfer a server side variable to a specific client's socket (passing a string color hex code) and running into an issue with the variable arriving as undefined once read in the client side. (passed as parameter in an emit event). I've been looking over the documentation and similar questions and have arrived at the following code for myself

Server socket setup:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));

 
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());

const server = require("http").createServer(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT"],
        credentials: true
    },
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/public")));

let info = [];
let colors = ["#fc0da1", "#4a00b5", "#43b3ae", "#abd98c", "#e600ff", "#82aa9a", "#0ebabd", "#722f37", "#fed400", "#F54D28", "#2F59A7", "#016A13", "#963D97", "#1B8751", "#CCFF00", "#4D8C57", "#00CCCC", "#C62D42"];
let usedColors = [];

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    info.push(socket);
    if(colors.length === 1){
        socket.color = colors[0];
        usedColors.push(colors.pop(0));
        colors = usedColors;
        usedColors = [];
    }
    else{
        let color = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
        socket.color = colors[color];
        usedColors.push(colors.pop(color));
        console.log(socket.color);
    }
    io.to(socket.id).emit("getColor", socket.color);
});
```

And the set up on the client side is this:

```
const socket = io();
let chatColor;
```

and the client emit event setup being this:

```
socket.on("getColor", function(color){
        console.log(color);
        chatColor = color;
    })
```

I can confirm that on the server side the socket is successfully handed the hex code string as a field, but it's not passing successfully. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I'm a socket novice.

Comment: did you try omitting the .to() and just call emit on io? i mean like this,           io.emit("getColor", socket.color)

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either. Also I need to emit the event for only that one socket's client side, and the documentation seems to suggest using to.(id). From what I understand the server and client socket will both have the same id value

Comment: it might be because io is not defined properly, try this step below as it worked for me many times: const { Server } = require("socket.io");   const io = new Server(server);

Comment: Ok I'll try it, did you put that on the server side?